# VBA error handling for function to check if worksheet exists

Tags: vba, error-handling

I have a function that will add a worksheet and rename it, but first checks to see if a worksheet by that name already exists. To do that, I'm using the pretty widely available function here -

```
Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next ' Set to Resume Next as don't want to end macro if this fails
    WorksheetExists = (Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

My problem is that I have already set `On Error GoTo error_exit` in the parent sub that calls this function, so `On Error GoTo 0` after checking if the sheet exists nulifies that call.

I've tried `On Error GoTo error_exit` in this function, but I get the following error -

> Complie Error: Label not defined

Does anybody know how I could work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you exit from the Function `WorksheetExists` your error scope is automatically resumed to the previous situation.
You don't need to do anything to resume the `On Error Goto error_exit` in the calling sub/function.

It is interesting to note, that if you remove the error handling from this function and a worksheet with the passed name doesn't exists, your code will resume execution on the calling error handling label (i.e. at the error_exit: label in the calling code)

Comment: @DavidGard: Adding to this, you can therefore remove the `On Error GoTo 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (sorry for the delay, I've been on holiday). I will do some editing when I return to work and see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean without using On Error Resume Next which most programmers dislike and which also means that during debugging you can't use 'Break On All Errors' to get the code to stop dead (Tools->Options->General->Error Trapping->Break on All Errors).

For me one solution is to bury any On Error Resume Next into a compiled DLL, in the old days this would have been VB6.  Today you could use VB.NET but I choose to use C#.

If Visual Studio is available to you then here is some source.  The pattern is like C#'s TryParse which returns boolean indicating successful but also returns the result in a return parameter (or out parameter in C# parlance)

Here is C# source, start a Class Library calling it BuryVBAErrorsCS, set ComVisible(true) add a reference to COM library 'Microsoft Excel n', click Register for Interop.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BuryVBAErrorsCS
{
    // Requires adding a reference to COM library Microsoft Excel 
    // In AssemblyInfo.cs set ComVisible(true);
    // In Build tab check 'Register for Interop'
    public interface ICollectionItemTry
    {
        bool SheetsItemTry(Sheets worksheetsCol, object vItem, out Worksheet result);
        bool WorkbooksItemTry(Workbooks workbooksCol, object vItem, out Workbook result);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ICollectionItemTry))]
    public class CCollectionItemTry : ICollectionItemTry
    {
        public bool SheetsItemTry(Sheets worksheetsCol, object vItem, out Worksheet result)
        {
            result = null;
            try
            {
                result = worksheetsCol.Item[vItem];
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            return false;
        }

        public bool WorkbooksItemTry(Workbooks workbooksCol, object vItem, out Workbook result)
        {
            result = null;
            try
            {
                result = workbooksCol.Item[vItem];
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

For Excel client VBA code here is some source

```
Sub TestCCollectionItemTry()
    Dim o As BuryVBAErrorsCS.CCollectionItemTry
    Set o = New BuryVBAErrorsCS.CCollectionItemTry

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Debug.Assert Not o.SheetsItemTry(ThisWorkbook.Sheets, "Sheet3366", ws)
    Debug.Assert ws Is Nothing

    '* sanity check
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
    Debug.Assert Not ws Is Nothing

    '* assuming Sheet1 exists
    Set ws = Nothing
    Debug.Assert o.SheetsItemTry(ThisWorkbook.Sheets, "Sheet1", ws)
    Debug.Assert Not ws Is Nothing

    Set ws = Nothing
    Debug.Assert o.SheetsItemTry(ThisWorkbook.Sheets, 1, ws)
    Debug.Assert Not ws Is Nothing

    '* workbooks
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Debug.Assert o.WorkbooksItemTry(Application.Workbooks, 1, wb)
    Debug.Assert Not wb Is Nothing

    Set wb = Nothing
    Debug.Assert o.WorkbooksItemTry(Application.Workbooks, ThisWorkbook.Name, wb)
    Debug.Assert Not wb Is Nothing

    Set wb = Nothing
    Debug.Assert Not o.WorkbooksItemTry(Application.Workbooks, "BonzoDogDoodah.xls", wb)
    Debug.Assert wb Is Nothing


End Sub
```

**NOTE WELL** Pass in the Sheets collection instead of the Worksheets collection.